# Model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

I have two models Library and Book. In my Library model, I have an array - book_ids. The primary key of Book model is ID.

How do I create a has_many :books relation in my library model?

This is a legacy database we are using with rails.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you put an array of anything into a database column?

Comment: It is a stored as a string "[3,4,5]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database schema doesn't really conform with the prescribed Rails conventions so you will probably have a hard time making the default has_many association work. Have you tried fiddling with the custom SQL options with it thought?

If you can't get the built in `has_many` association to work, you'll have to roll your own. I would define the `books` and `books=` methods on your Library model, and inside them set a virtual attribute, which you then save as an array in the database. Perhaps something like this:

```
class Book > ActiveRecord::Base; end

class Library > ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :serialize_books

  def books
    @books || nil
  end

  def books=(new_books)
    @books = new_books
  end

  private
  def serialize_books
    @attributes['books'] = "[" + @books.collect {|b| b.id }.join(',') + "]"
  end
end
```

That up there wouldn't pull out the dataIf you wanted to go even more gung ho and support single query find operations, you could use some custom SQL in a scope or override find and add it to the default options. Comment if you want help with any of this!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use has_many you could use the options :counter_sql and :finder_sql using the MySQL LIKE or REGEX syntax. But its probably better to first load the Libary model, then parse the book_ids column and load the books, or directly build a query with that string.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using :serialize method with ActiveRecord:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002284

it might do what you want